# Updating g++ version through to match homebrew version

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal, g++

I recently installed gcc@5 from homebrew. When I type `g++ --version` it shows that I have 4.2.1 installed and from `brew list` it shows that I have gcc@5. I want to be able to compile code with the latest g++ version so that I can have access to c++11. I tried switching over to my `usr/bin` folder and trying to change my g++ version with `sudo ln -s -f g++-@5 g++` but it leaves me with this error: `ln: g++: Operation not permitted`. I don't want to constantly type `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp - o test` every time I want to compile my program with c++11 specific keywords such as `=default`.

I have macOS Sierra and I'm pretty new to macOS. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why don't you use a build system such as [SCONS](http://scons.org) or [CMake](https://cmake.org) rather than constantly typing in compiler options and filenames by hand?

Comment: Xcode on Sierra ships with Clang, not GCC, so you don't have any GCC 4.2.1 installed unless you installed one by yourself, nor you need GCC 5.0 for C++11 support since Xcode 8 is on par with C++14 and even some features of C++17. How did you determine that you have gcc installed? `g++` command wraps directly Clang on OS X.

Comment: What dies `which g++` give? You must modify your `path` environment variable, I suspect. BTW, the most recent GCC is 6.something.

Comment: @Jesper Jihl I compile it by hand when I only have 1 cpp file, and I use makefile when I have multiple.                                                                 @Jack When I type `clang++ test.cpp -o test` I still get the warning `warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`. I rather compile it on terminal rather than using Xcode.